# Do I need a visa for 1 week holiday in Istanbul, from Netherlands?

Tags: visas, turkey, istanbul, italian-citizens

I live in Amsterdam, Netherlands. I'm Italian. I want to visit Istanbul for 1 week in March. Do I need a visa?

Comment: What citizenship do you have? Dutch? Makes a difference.

Comment: @MarkMayo Italian citizenship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If were a citizen of the Kingdom of the Netherlands, with a passport issued by that country, you would need a [visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

If you are a citizen of Italy, with a passport issued by the Kingdom of the Netherlands, again, you would need a visa.

If you are an Italian citizen, with a passport issued by the government of Italy, then you are exempt, as you yourself indicate.

Comment: If you are an Italian citizen, and not have dual citizenship with the Netherlands as the other one, you can not have a passport issued by the Kingdom of the Netherlands.

Comment: I see that the eVisa replaces the *queue for a sticker from a bored guard at the airport* system. Issuance was immediate; the point was collection of fees. In particular, the fee for USA citizens was quite high in reflection of the fee the USA charged Turkish visa applicants.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're Dutch, you need to get a visa. You do this online:

https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/

Comment: Hi, I went to the website you told me and I've actually been told I'm exempted. (I'm Italian not Dutch). It says: You are exempt from visa for tourist visits of up to 90 days within 180 days starting from the first entry date.

Comment: The visit date is 27 February.

Comment: ps. the down vote wasn't from me, just in case :)

Comment: Thanks. I won't be losing sleep over it, but I was quite surprised.

Answer (score -1):

Updated Post:

Italian citizens do not need a visa to visit Turkey.

For future visa questions for Italian citizens, although it isn't always accurate, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Italian_citizens)

Comment: Please see comment to other answer.

Comment: I find your downvote to be absolutely unjustified. When you originally posted your question, you simply said that you live in the Netherlands. Thus, unless otherwise stated one can infer that you are a citizen of that country. I posted an answer directed towards Dutch citizens. Then you edited your post to indicate that you were Italian, downvoting the replies posted before you indicated that you were of a different nationality. How can posters be expected to know you are an Italian citizen, when you live in the Netherlands unless you tell us? Nevertheless, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't put the down vote, it wasn't me. I appreciated your answer. I find silly that stack overflow doesn't allow to know who set the votes. It's easy to misunderstood. So don't be pissed off with me, because I didn't do it. (ps. you got 2 down votes, and 1 vote up.

Comment: @Patrick My apologies, I assumed that it was you. Please excuse me.